# When is it optimal to rebuy Kevlar?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

At what point should I buy Kevlar in CS:GO? I have a very bad habit of constantly rebuying kevlar every round during a match, and it really drains my funds quickly.

At what point is it safe to rebuy armor?

Comment: If you're rebuying kevlar every round, then it sounds like it's saving your life.

Comment: If my armor goes down from 100 to 95, and I rebuy, I think at that point it's kind of a waste of money.

Comment: once my kev reaches 75 or lower I usually buy again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Armor, as long as you have it, will have the same reduction regardless of how much. Example: 50 armor reduces bullet damage just as much as 100. The only time you need to rebuy is if your armor will drop to 0 during the round (2-3 bullets worth) since 0 armor provides no bullet damage reduction. *Rule of thumb typically is around 40, you should rebuy.*

**Sources:**

- http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Kevlar_Armor/Helmet
- http://www.hattongames.com/2013/03/quick-tips-should-i-always-wear-protection/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1dzj8h/when_should_i_rebuy_a_kevlarhelmet/